# What should we do with this answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

[This](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/55574/1467) in particular.

It got flagged, as not an answer, [it passed review](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/35506) and now is flagged again.

What should we do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I don't see how it answers the question "Do any airports have a steeper standard approach than London City?", since, as said in the comments, the mentioned airport is only mildly steeper than a usual approach.

I would vote to delete.

Answer (score 2):

When I saw it earlier, I thought it was not an answer, but I'm having second thoughts. The poster thought of an airport that may have a steeper approach. As it turns out, that was wrong, and the airport has a shallower approach. As an outright, unsupported guess, it's a pretty poor quality answer, but it *is* a good-faith attempt to answer the question. The fact that it was wrong doesn't make it NAA, and we don't typically delete answers just for being wrong.

That said, remember the rule to "optimise for pearls, not sand". This attempt at an answer is definitely sand, not pearls, so let's not worry too much about it either way.

Comment: Totally agree. Correct answer, no. High quality answer, no. Gives an answer to the question as stated, **yes**.  It also allows somebody with the same hunch to see that in fact no, this airport is ***not*** the right answer, even though its reputation brings it to mind.

Comment: If by 'optimise for pearls, not sand', you mean this [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/), then I think sand is about questions, not answers. I may be missing your point.

Comment: @ymb1 I think it's about content in general. Sometimes just-OK questions can lead to great answers. This isn't one of those, and I don't think deleting it would be a big loss to the site (or even a big loss to this question).

Comment: I get it now. I understand the sensitivity and technicality around the term 'NAA', but I'd suggest making it clearer in the post that you are not against deleting this particular answer. It wasn't clear, to me at least. Thanks @DanHulme.